# Does The Saboteur run without any problems on current AMD graphics cards?

Tags: technical-issues, hardware, graphics-card, the-saboteur

When it came out, The Saboteur either didn't run at all on AMD cards, or produced crashes and artifacts. Pandemic published a quick and dirty fix before being closed down forever, but this fix didn't work for all users, didn't fix all crashes/problems (e.g. the map overlays were wrongly scaled on my computer), and on multi-core systems, needed a manual setting of the game process's "processor affinity" to core 1.

This prompted me to change my graphics card, and I have never bought an AMD card since (and did also never again have problems with The Saboteur).

But is this still the case for new AMD cards? **Does The Saboteur run reliably on current AMD graphics? Is the patch still needed?**

Comment: I cannot answer the question, but I'd like to point out something about the multi core issues: Saboteur out of the box does not run with CPUs with more than 4 cores (real cores apparently), even with the setting of the cpu affinity.
https://www.gog.com/forum/the_saboteur/game_does_not_start_at_all/post43 mentions a way to fix this by hexediting the executable.